# Как удалить строку из MySQL через pyTelegrambot

Tags: python, mysql, telebot

Пишу пошаговое создание анкеты через телеграм бота.
Тут окончание создания, запись вносится в БД

```
def process_about_step(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_dict[user_id]
        about = message.text
        user.about = about
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нужная информация собрана!\n\nВот твоя анкета:\n\n' + user.city  + '\n'  + user.name + ', ' + str(user.age) + '\n\n' + about )
        sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, city, age, sex, about, user_id) VALUES  (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        val = (user.name, user.city, user.age, user.sex, user.about, user_id)
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        #ПОДТВЕРЖДЕНИЕ ЗАНЕСЕНИЯ
        mydb.commit()
        print(mycursor.rowcount, 'запись добавлена')
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
        markup.add('Начать поиск', 'Заполнить анкету заново')
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Что ты хочешь сделать?", reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_choice_step)

    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Дальше шаг выбора.
Не пойму как реализовать чтобы нажимая на кнопку "Заполнить анкету заново" бот начинал создание анкеты заново и введенные данные юзером ранее **удалились** или **изменились на те, которые он введет пройдя заново.**
Это не работает

```
def process_choice_step(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_dict[user_id]
        reset_profile = message.text
        if reset_profile == 'Заполнить анкету заново':
            sql = "DELETE users WHERE name = %s AND city = %s AND age = %s AND age = %s AND sex = %s AND about = %s AND user_id = %s"
            mycursor.execute(sql)
            mydb.commit()
            print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) deleted")
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Хорошо\nЗаполним анкету заново")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_name_step)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'не понимаю')

    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

`def process_name_step` - это первый этап регистрации

Answer (score 0):

При выполнении запроса удаления вы не передаете сами данные для SQL запроса. 
Примерный вид корректного запроса на удаление данных из базы данных:

```
sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = %s"
val = (user_id)
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
```

Comment: У меня колонка user_id имеет уникальное значение, т.к. в телеграмме у каждого он свой.
Если я прописываю `delete from users user_id = user_id`, то удаляются все записи, данные других юзеров.
Не пойму как прописать чтоб только строка(данные) удалились 1 юзера, куда в `user_id = (сюда)' автоматом подставлялся user_id , то есть его уникальный id